# Cakephp change what's selectable based on what parent is selected?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have three models:

MODEL A

->HABTM MODEL B

MODEL B

->BELONGSTO MODEL C

MODEL C

->HASMANY MODEL B

I'm creating a new model A. I want to select a Model C from a dropdown, and have that populate a multiselect with all of that Model C's Model Bs. The user can then select which of these Model Bs(HABTM) he wants.

What's the easiest way to accomplish this with CakePHP?

Answer (score 0):

It needs several steps. You can do it with several actions, or one action with a parameter. First, find('list') model C to display. After the user choose, select all model B records belong to that model C, include that in a model A form. Check here: http://book.cakephp.org/view/1034/Saving-Related-Model-Data-HABTM for how to save the data.